# Is there any way to iterate return next element in Mongo collection every time?

Tags: multithreading, mongodb

I have a mongodb collection with documents.
Several processes call to this collection, so I need to return next element everytime they call it. Is there any internal mongo counter for this? I've tried to realize it, but multithread programs are in conflict, so it doesn't work...

p.s. Maybe there are any ways to iterate string data for several process? I don't really need mongodb here

Comment: It depends on what language and environment are you using. See documentation for appropriate driver. See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/cursors/

Comment: @saleem I use php mongodb drive, but that cursor is not what I searching for. I have several apps and 1 storage with some data, that it uses. So, If app "A" called storage, it will get element with id 1. Then, when app "B" call this storage, it will get element with id 2.

Comment: How about incrementing a atomic variable and save back to db. Next operation do same? This is not an ideal solution but will work. See $set

Comment: @Saleem this will not work in mongo imho, as many threads can read 2 and try to store 3...

Comment: @AlexeyBerezuev could you elaborate more about your problem? For me it looks like there is a need for message queue than storage.